# node-qrcode install on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I got problem to install this package on heroku.
Is there a way to do it ?

I saw it's a problem with canvas module, but i don't know what to do.

This is a log of installation on heroku. I don't know how to get more :

```
npm ERR! canvas@0.12.1 preinstall: `node-waf configure build`
       npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@0.12.1 preinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
       npm ERR! not with npm itself.
       npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
       npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
       npm ERR! You can get their info via:
       npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
       npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-343-ec2
       npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-La1F/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-6Xts/cli.js" "install" "--production"
       npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_3ejt8evom1p0g
       npm ERR! node -v v0.6.18
       npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.41
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! stack Error: canvas@0.12.1 preinstall: `node-waf configure build`
       npm ERR! stack `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
       npm ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/node-npm-6Xts/lib/utils/exec.js:56:20)
       npm ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
       npm ERR! stack     at maybeExit (child_process.js:362:16)
       npm ERR! stack     at Process.onexit (child_process.js:398:5)
```

Comment: Can you post your full build output?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used this Heroku builpack:
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mojodna/heroku-buildpack-cairo

But in its README, it tells you to use *heroku-buildpack-multi*, that's deprecated. What I did was, using Heroku Toolbelt in command line:

> heroku buildpacks:set --index 1 https://github.com/mojodna/heroku-buildpack-cairo.git
>
> heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs

And then push to Heroku so it can build packages again.